# CSS3 styling v/s jQuery styling - which is better?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been in a dilemma lately on whether to use CSS3 for styling and animations (which I'd planned to learn) or stick with jQuery/javascript. I use jQuery and javascript for such because I feel they're more stable and can be viewed in all the major browsers. But CSS3 is progressively growing and has really great features that can be used without linking external files.
So, which do you think would be better? Should I stick with jQuery and javascript or should I learn CSS3?

Thanks.

**Edit:** Some effects like rounded corners, fading, and even simple slideshows and lightbox can be achieved by CSS3. Now if I can achieve such without javascript, I would surely use CSS3. But older browsers won't support it unless the effects are javascript based, which is my concern. If my clients and their customers view a website I styled with CSS3 and find the website messed up, that would be a problem for me. So that why I asked you guys to guide me with this. Should I use CSS3 for simple effects, or should I use javascript for that? I know I sound like a fool, but I need to get better! :)

Comment: the question makes entirely no sense. Its comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Yes and no, for some animations, you can use CSS3 or jQuery. For styling, I'd take as much CSS as possible

Comment: You've already listed the pros and cons, which makes this completely subjective (unless people care to take a middle road and just say "look at your audience").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't let the fact that CSS3 adoption is still being hindered by older browsers stop you learning how to use it. I would learn it now, in readiness for when it becomes the required standard.

My personal preference is to incorporate any CSS3 feature I need, and use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com) as a fallback for old/poorly specced browsers (yes, IE, I mean you).

Comment: Or use any CSS3 feature you need and give IE a page without CSS, because you know, they don't deserve pretty.

Comment: IE users deserve pretty, but THEY GOTTA PAY.

Comment: By pay do you mean we take them out back and break their legs? Mafia style.

Comment: I meant money, but I like your plan too.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I stick with jQuery and javascript or should I learn CSS3?

Why is it a choice of one or the other? (In particular why is one of the choices *learning* CSS3 rather than *using* CSS3?)

I'd suggest you learn CSS3 even if you don't use it *yet* for all projects, so at least you have the option of using it when appropriate.

Meanwhile, as you pointed out there are some browser compatibility issues so if that is an issue (and it probably is for public websites) you could stick with jQuery and/or JavaScript.